# Chrome 53 introduces unwanted spacing in LI elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, blink

Starting Chrome 53 we have noticed a new CSS-related issue.

This issue can also be seen in Vivaldi (which is based on the same engine as Chrome). The same issue is not seen in Safari or Firefox or Chrome 52.

For example, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/

[image]

Is this a spec change that requires updating our CSS or an actual bug in the rendering engine?

**Update**: It is seemingly happening because of `list-style-position:inside`.

```html
<ul style="list-style-position:inside">
    <li>li element 1</li>
    <li>li element 2</li>
</ul>
```

When used, in addition for the LI element getting pushed inside as expected, the spacing between the bullet and the text increases as well. Remove the CSS rule and the spacing between the bullet and the text is much smaller.

How can we address this?

Comment: Someone marked this for closure because it's not about programming? Are you kidding me...? It's about CSS. It is completely on-topic.

Comment: No, they voted to close because of this "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." Emphasis mine. Please provide a test case, and don't just link to off-site resources.

Comment: Understood. Done.

Comment: Still there in canary (55). File a bug, and they'll tell you if they're following specs, then open one in other browsers.

Comment: Done. See here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=644630

Comment: According to a google engineer in the issue above, this is an expected change to align with the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't say if this is a quirk or a spec change, but a workaround would be to set the list-style to outside, and instead of padding use a left margin:

```
.tutorial .sidebar .navmenu-default .navmenu-nav.dropdown-menu>li.active>ul>li {
      list-style-position: outside;
}
.tutorial .sidebar ul {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
```